# How can I apply NotebookGet on invisible Notebooks?

Tags: notebooks

My problem might be very specific, but can be quickly explained:

First I create an invisible notebook nb by CreateDocument, then i apply NotebookGet on it to see its content, wich works fine!
Now I want to evaluate the Cells in the created invisible Notebook, so i apply NotebookEvaluate on it. After this i can not use NotebookGet anymore (it returnes $Failed) and i dont understand why.

Here is a little code-example:

```
nb = CreateDocument[Cell["1+1" // StandardForm, "Input"], 
  Visible -> False];
NotebookGet[nb]
NotebookEvaluate[nb, InsertResults -> True]
NotebookGet[nb]
```

Off course i could use the Returnvalue of NotebookEvaluate in this example, but thats not the point. I maybe want to have more than one Outputcell.

It would be very nice if someone could answer this question.

**EDIT:**

I have "9.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (November 20, 2012)"

For some reason now my Mathematica completely crashes if i evaluate my little example code. Might be a problem of my System.

**EDID**

I meanwhile found a workaround of my problem that does not use an extra notebook. My aim was just to evaluate the content of a Cell seperatly (not only inside the notebook) and i did not thought about using ToExpression. My way with a seperate notebook was way to complicated. Here goes a little example of how to reada Cell and get the unevaluated expression and the result of the expression.

```
read = NotebookRead[EvaluationCell[]];
expr = ToExpression[ReplaceAll[read, Cell[x__, y__] :> x], 
StandardForm, Hold]
```

My problem is solved thanks.

Comment: Your code works for me (OSX v10.0.2). What Mathematica version do you have ?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I use 9.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (November 20, 2012)

For some reason now my Mathematica completely crashes if i evaluate my little example code. Might be a problem of my System.

Comment: @sacratus Actually, I have also v9.0.1.0 (January 24,2013), and YES it crashes immediately the whole session when `Visible->False` !! No crash when `Visible->False`. Explain better what you try do do, maybe there might be a workaround. (By the way, when replying to somebody in particular in a comment, you have to specify his name at the begining of the comment as I did here otherwise the person won't be notified)

Comment: @SquareOne Thanks for your hints, most people on this site seam to be very polite and helpfull. I like how new users like me are getting introduced to the structure of this site!
I meanwhile found a bether way to solve my Problem with not using an extra (invisible) notebook. See my last EDIt on the question.